# How do I access this variable outside of my class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

```
class DayFix:
    def __init__(self, year, month, day):
        self.year = year
        self.month = month
        self.day = day
    def fix(self):
        if self.month > 12:
            self.year += 1
            self.month = 1
        elif self.month == 2 and self.day > 29:
            self.month += 1
            self.day = 1
        elif self.month == 4 or self.month == 6 or self.month == 9 or self.month == 11:
            if self.day > 30:
                self.month += 1
                self.day = 1
        elif self.month == 1 or self.month == 3 or self.month == 5 or self.month == 7 or self.month == 8 or self.month == 10:
            if self.day > 31:
                self.month += 1
                self.day = 1
        elif self.month == 12 and self.day > 31:
            self.year += 1
            self.month = 1
            self.day = 1
        test_date = '' + str(self.year) + '-' + str(self.month) + '-' + str(self.day) + ''
        tof = bool(len(pd.bdate_range(test_date, test_date)))
        while tof == False:
            self.day += 1
            test_date = '' + str(self.year) + '-' + str(self.month) + '-' + str(self.day) + ''
            tof = bool(len(pd.bdate_range(test_date, test_date)))
            if tof == True:
                break
```

Yes, I am aware it probably looks like trash, I am very new to this. I need to use the updated "test_date" variable after it goes through the while loop outside of the class, but I am not sure how to get it after running the class with:

```
d = DayFix(2020, 1, 10)
d.fix()
```

Thanks ahead of time.

Have not tried any fix yet, not sure what to expect.

Comment: You cannot access local variables from a function. You can save the values needed outside as attributes, e.g. `self.test_date = test_date`, or you can `return test_date` from the function.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see [ask]. Describe your problem before showing Code. Please also see [What should I keep out of my posts and titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131009/997587) (includes self-deprecation, and "thanks in advance"). [You also don't need to tell us that you are new to `X`. It is just noise here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296391/11107541).

Comment: `fix` shouldn't be defined at all, or at least called from inside `__init__`. Once `__init__` returns, an instance of `DayFix` should already be valid, without requiring whoever called `DayFix` to then "fix" it.